UI elements jitter when being conditionally rendered
I'm have an issue where buttons and links jitter on state change (when clicking on the "Sign Out" button). I tried both v-if and v-show and the jitter persists.
Video of the issue: https://www.veed.io/view/89672f51-f55c-411c-883f-440b02cfa4de?panel=share
Reproduction: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-a8hntf?file=app%2Fcomposables%2FuseStoreAuth.ts.
<div>
  <div>
      <button @click="setColorTheme()">
          <IconDarkMode />
      </button>
      <div v-if="!signedIn && !pending">
          <NuxtLink to="/sign-in">
              <span>Sign In</span>
              <IconSignIn />
          </NuxtLink>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div
      v-if="signedIn && !pending">
      <NuxtLink to="/profile">
          <span>Profile</span>
          <IconProfile />
      </NuxtLink>
      <button to="/sign-in" @click="signOut">
          <span>Sign Out</span>
          <IconSignOut />
      </button>
  </div>
</div>

I also have a 300ms delay for signedIn state in signOut function to wait until page transition ends, but jitter still persists.
if (res.ok) {
    const data = await res.json();
    state.successMessage = data.message;
    if (route.path === '/') {
        window.location.reload();
    } else {
        window.location.href = '/';
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
        state.signedIn = data.signedIn;
    }, 300);
}

Looking for a possible solution.

The question needs a way to reproduce to understand what happens, but that you use window.location means the page will be reloaded and rerendered, some flickering is inevitable besides other downsides. There's potentially no reason to do this.

@EstusFlask I basically want to wait until the page fades and during that phase I want to change buttons, so that the process of changing them isn't visible to the user. But instead right now it changes even before the transition starts. I might try to reproduce.

You're reloading the page, so you're not in control how this is visualized. Currently it looks like you misused window.location, and what you have is the consequence. Generally you use router.push for navigation, window.location is for exotic cases

I see, I used navigateTo before but it acted strange, so I wanted to try window.location instead to see if there's any difference. Works same to me

I remember the previous question. It's a wrong direction here, it can only make flickering worse. Afaik there's nothing in navigateTo and nuxtlink themselves that unconditionally make it behave like that, so it needs to be debugged what happens and what's wrong

@EstusFlask here you go, I've made a reproduction. https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-a8hntf?file=app%2Fcomposables%2FuseStoreAuth.ts. So, I want the page, including the header to reload when I click 'sign out' and so that there's no jitter, In my opinion, it should happen in the middle of the transition and not before, so it's not visible to the user. You can test the behavior by going to /about, then clicking sign in and then sign out.

Thanks. From what I see, it's "pending" condition that forces the layout to jump. I'm not sure how it's supposed to look like in the end, but it's not needed there if you need transitions, i.e. either one of these divs with v-ifs should exist in the layout an any moment of time

@EstusFlask You're right about pending causing the issue. Initially, I added it for safety, to make sure signedIn is set to true when the cookie is set and vice versa. However, the issue with buttons change before page transition begins persists. It's solvable by adding a delay of 300ms (same as page transition) to state.signedIn = data.signedIn;, but I'm not sure if it's a safe solution. I feel like I'm making it all from mud and straw. Is it how it's supposed to work in most Nuxt/Vue apps? Do component libraries like Quasar/Vuetify handle these details under the hood? I use Radix.

If I understood your concern correctly, you need to use separate state for UI that will differ from store.signedIn and use to promises for correct control flow.  I.e onSignOutClick = async () => { await store.signOut(); uiSignedIn.value = store.signedIn }. Also navigateTo and router methods return promises, you may want to await them too. I'm not sure about other libs, but I don't see transitions much in places like menus

@EstusFlask I agree. It seems like a better solution. I will also remove the transition from buttons, since it's not needed anymore.

@EstusFlask I should probably await only navigateTo('/'), since router.go(0) doesn't return a promise.

The solution is recommended by @Estus Flask in the comments above.
Regarding the UI element jitter:

It's "pending" condition that forces the layout to jump. It's not needed there if you need transitions, i.e. either one of these divs
with v-ifs should exist in the layout an any moment of time.

Regarding the buttons changing before page transition starts:

You need to use separate state for UI that will differ from store.signedIn and use to promises for correct control flow. I.e
onSignOutClick = async () => { await store.signOut(); uiSignedIn.value = store.signedIn }. Also, navigateTo and router methods return promises, you may want to await them too.


I think the issue is the button's element prop "to" with the click event.
here is an example of logic you should try:
signOut() {
  try {
    // first handle your logic
    // request logout from server
    // delete cookies and sesion
    // after success push to route and then change signedIn state(if its not a dynamic value)
    router.push("/sign-in");
    signedIn.value = false
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("logout::error", error);
  }
},

First handle your logout logic, on success you handle the route and other states, don't use the to="sign-in" if your logic in the click is a asynchronous function.
I also recommend adding a fade animation, on the button, it will help prevent the jitter.

But sign out is a button, not NuxtLink. So I removed setTimeout and I tried to apply <TransitionGroup name="page" mode="out-in"> for buttons with the same name as in the page transition, but even though I added a class .page-leave-active {position: absolute;} as it says here https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition-group, I still have this behavior when signing out: https://www.veed.io/view/5c3babc8-0cbb-44b9-a028-83ccdf44fe83?panel=share. Looks like the page transition appears after the button transition and there's still a jitter, but now it's vertical.

right now the logic is next: if (route.path === '/') { router.go(0); state.signedIn = data.signedIn; } else { navigateTo('/'); }. So if I'm already at '/' I just want to reload the page, and otherwise navigate to '/'. navigateTo is the same as router.push(), but specific to Nuxt.

I updated the question and added the reproduction.
